# Sybase ASE migration, "Opentable was passed a varno of %d." (Error 622)

Tags: sybase, procedure, sap-ase, descriptor

I am seeking for help because I am having troubles with an ASE 15.7 database server which has a 12.5.4 backup loaded up. A procedure that runs well on the old environnement (12.5.4) brings up an error 622 on the new one (15.7) :

> Error: 622, Severity: 20, State: 1. Opentable was passed a varno of
>   54. Object 'temp worktable' in database 'tempdb' already has that session descriptor in use. This occurred while opening object id
>   -1769526 in database id 2.

Would you please have any idea on how to fix this? I am afraid something went wrong when loading the database dump.
Would there be any configuration mismatch between the two environments that'd make this working on 12.5.4 but not 15.7?

Comment: You loaded this from a dump, did you go through the recommended upgrade procedures?  Have you tried restarting your Sybase server?  You should share with us as much information as you can about what did to get to this point, and what you have tried to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I  didn't really follow any strict procedure. I created a new ASE 15.7 instance with a pagesize of 2k (like my dump from 12.5.4 was). I then ran `load database _databaseName_ from "backup.dump"` and it imported all the content using its cross-platform procedure.
To fix  the issue I tried to increase the `tempdb` database size, turn off statement cache with `set statement_cache off` and rebooted the server. It wouldn't fix the problem.

Comment: Next thing I would try is recompiling the stored procedures, and doing an reorg.  SAP also recommends running the `preupgrade` utility before going upgrading from such an old version. http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc31644.1570/html/sag2/X25861.htm

Comment: I see yes, thanks for the advise. I read somewhere that I had to recompile the stored procedures and revise the indexes or something but I couldn't find the commands to do this at once for all the tables. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Would it work if I enable compatibility mode server-wide and try loading the dump afterwards?

Comment: I tried the `preupgrade` command but it wouldn't really tell me much. It seemed like it wanted me to do it before the database goes online (right after the dump has been loaded) so I dropped and recreated the database. After that, I retried and it told me something like the database is offline and it has to skip it... I tried so many things and I am still getting this error, not knowing whether the compatibility mode is actually working well or not. Thank you for your help

Comment: I realized now that the execution of the stored procedure crashes the connexion because of its join with a view. Would this info help you to spot the problem? I ran `sp_recompile` on the tables so that the stored procedure can be recompiled, but I can't do this with views. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: dbcc upgrade_object should allow you to recompile any non-table objects. See the [Upgrade Guide](http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc35888.1502/html/aseigwin/X20119.htm) and the [dbcc command guide](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1570/html/commands/X60179.htm)

Comment: Thank you. I ran that but still not fixing my issue. `dbcc upgrade_object` returned a bunch of unfound objects (like `ActiviteEtabMP not found. Specify owner.objectname or use sp_help to check whether the object exists (sp_help may produce lots of output).`). Does it mean they are still in the sysobjects table but they don't exist anymore? How could I clean this? How can I make sure all the other objects have been upgraded? Thank you for your help

Comment: I am getting really desperate. This doesn't make any sense at all. Told you that if I remove the `join left vw_EntrepriseActive ...` from the SQL code executed in the SP, it works. I realised now that when it won't work, Toad for Sybase warns me with `Stored procedure 'dbo....' not found. Specify owner.objectname or use sp_help to check whether the object exists (sp_help may produce lots of output).`. But when I remove that `left join`, it doesn't complain anymore at all!! >< Any idea? Thanks

Comment: So after some testing I can now tell the view is the cause since I can't even access the data returned by the view from Toad for Sybase. I get the same error. Although, I cannot understand what is wrong with it. Any idea of what it could be? Thank you

Comment: I would check the underlying tables for the view, make sure there aren't any issues, then drop and recreate the view.

Comment: Also, you may have some luck over in the [SAP Community Network: ASE for Custom Applications](http://scn.sap.com/community/ase-custom-applications/content) content area.  Some of the principle engineers for ASE check in there regularly to help out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75524/discussion-between-mentinet-and-michael-gardner).